# How to structure a JVM project to isolate proprietary code?

Tags: java, scala, version-control, compilation, sbt

I have a scala project managed by SBT, which includes a number of classes that are adapters that link to proprietary code. These have commercial licenses that preclude distribution of linked libraries, as well as the adapter code that I've written myself.

I want to isolate these adapters from the rest of my code so that I could in theory distribute my project as open-source. I need to ensure that each adapter

- Is version-controlled separately.
- Can be selectively switched on/off during compilation & JAR creation (kind of like `--with-xxx` when running `./configure` in a C project)

**What should the directory structure of something like this look like? What about the SBT project(s)?** I'd like to adhere to the usual Gradle directory structure if possible.

The problem to consider is that each adapter depends on the core project (i.e. they inherit an `Adapter` interface defined in the main project), and in turn the core project depends on individual adapters. So I'm not sure how to set this up to avoid circular dependencies, while isolating the core code from the adapter code.

Comment: Are the dependencies of adapters on the core project needed for compilation of main source code or only for tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved this way:

1. Extract the adapter interface from the 'core' module into a new module 'adpater-api';
2. Declare it as a dependency for the 'core' module and all the adapter implementation modules;
3. Declare 'core' as a dependency of the adapter implementation modules.
4. Each module can be versioned separately.
5. And adapter implementation modules are packaged separately.

Project layout:

```
root
├── adapter-a
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           └── scala
├── adapter-api
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           └── scala
├── adapter-b
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           └── scala
└── core
    └── src
        └── main
            ├── resources
            └── scala
```

build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(adapterApi, core, adapterA, adapterB)

lazy val adapterApi = project
  .in(file("adapter-api"))
  .settings(
    version := "1.0"
  )

lazy val core = project
  .in(file("core"))
  .dependsOn(adapterApi)
  .settings(
    version := "1.5"
  )

lazy val adapterA = project
  .in(file("adapter-a"))
  .dependsOn(adapterApi, core)
  .settings(
    version := "1.2"
  )

lazy val adapterB = project
  .in(file("adapter-b"))
  .dependsOn(adapterApi, core)
  .settings(
    version := "1.0"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @thirstycrow ; this answers the first bullet point. How would this answer the second bullet point? If I do `publish` from the sbt console, I suspect this will package *the whole project* into one jar file, correct? How would I go about selectively including/excluding each adapter when packaging for a release?

Comment: @Luciano Each project is packaged without any of its dependencies. You can use the sbt-assembly plugin to build a fat jar, but that's not the default behavior.

Comment: To make things a bit cleaner, you can also use `git submodule` command to have one 'root' repo in source-control, and then individual 'adapter' repos that you want excluded / versioned separately.